# Is this a subset sum solution?

Tags: python-3.x, subset-sum

I was wondering if this is a valid solution to the subset sum problem.

The algorithm programmed in Python 3 checks al the numbers in an array and if the sum of two of them equals my sum variable adds the set of numbers to an array and in the end prints all the possible solutions.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

sum = 12

def check(array,sum):

    isCorrect = False

    possibleSets = []

    for i in array:

        for s in array:

            if i+s == sum:
                possibleSets.extend([(i,s)])
                isCorrect = True

    return possibleSets, isCorrect


print(check(arr,sum))
```